# Environment vars by Power Shell

Tags: windows, powershell, environment-variables, windows-8.1

How can I get environmet variables by Power Shell?
What command should I execute. I use Windows 8.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this command:

```
Get-ChildItem Env:
```

Output:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
Path                           D:\Perl\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\...
TEMP                           C:\DOCUME~1\kmyer\LOCALS~1\Temp
SESSIONNAME                    Console
PATHEXT                        .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.PS1;.PSC1
USERDOMAIN                     WINGROUP
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE         x86
SystemDrive                    C:
APPDATA                        C:\Documents and Settings\kmyer\Application Data
windir                         C:\WINDOWS
USERPROFILE                    C:\Documents and Settings\kmyer
```

Also check [Windows PowerShell Tip of the Week](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730964.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

For a given environment variable, such as Path, reference it like this:

```
$env:Path
```

To see all of the environment variables you can visit the Ps-Drive "env:"

```
cd env:
```

Therein you can see and change all of the environment variables.